# XML - use selected parameter value to modify the available values in another parameter

Tags: xml, t-sql

Just started at a new company, where the third party software they use uses a combination of XML and SQL to allow you to create custom reports for the end users to run.
Because it's 3rd party, the front end is expecting the named elements we use so no wiggle room there as far as I'm aware - documentation is pretty sparse as well.

There are basically 2 components to each report - an xml file which handles getting the data (with SQL queries in it), and an xsl file that formats the output. I'm not too bothered with the xsl bit at the moment.

Here's some data to illustrate:

```
if object_id('Customers') is not null
    drop table dbo.Customers

create table dbo.Customers
(
CustomerID int,
name varchar(50),
telno varchar(11),
LocationID int
)

if object_id('Locations') is not null
    drop table dbo.Locations
create table dbo.Locations
(
LocationID int,
name varchar(50),
)

insert into Locations
select 1, 'South West' union
select 2, 'South East' union
select 3, 'North West' union
select 4, 'North East'

insert into Customers
select 1, 'Customer A', '01234567891', 1 union
select 2, 'Customer B', '01263757891', 1 union
select 3, 'Customer C', '01235453671', 3 union
select 4, 'Customer D', '03567891333', 1 union
select 5, 'Customer E', '01234567891', 4 union
select 6, 'Customer F', '01233456671', 2 union
select 7, 'Customer G', '01236577891', 2
```

The xml file looks like this (version I've mocked up - not a real report / database):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<DocumentSource id="">
<Name>Report1</Name>
<Description>Report1</Description>
<Prompts>
    <Prompt mandatory="no" datatype="int" name="CustomerID"  label="Customer" dropdownsource="SELECT '0' as CustomerID, ' ALL Customers' as Description UNION SELECT CustomerID, ltrim(Name) FROM Customers Order by Description" defaultvalue="0"/>
    <Prompt mandatory="no" datatype="int" name="LocationID"  label="Location" dropdownsource="SELECT '0' as LocationID,' ALL Locations' as Description UNION SELECT LocationID, ltrim(Shortdesc) FROM Locations Order by Description" defaultvalue="0"/>
</Prompts>
    
<Sections>
           
    <Section id="Report1" Align = "Left" type="Table" repeat=""> 
        <Source type="SQL">
            <![CDATA[ 
                select
                c.name CustomerName,
                c.telno TelephoneNumber,
                l.Name Location
                from 
                Customers c
                join Locations l
                on c.locationid = l.locationid
                where c.customerid = ?
                and l.locationid = ?
            ]]>
        
        </Source> 
        
        <Parameters>
            <Parameter type="int" seq="1">CustomerID</Parameter>
            <Parameter type="int" seq="2">LocationID</Parameter>
        </Parameters>   

        <Field name="CustomerName" type="String">CustomerName</Field>
        <Field name="TelephoneNumber" type="String">TelephoneNumber</Field>
        <Field name="Location" type="String">Location</Field>
    </Section>
</Sections>
</DocumentSource>
```

So the `<Prompts>` bit renders in the front end of the application as drop down lists (or date fields or whatever you define them as), and looks like this:

[Front end render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLWaN.png)

When the user has selected the value they want, the `<Parameters>` section defines the order the parameters are passed into the SQL query (as "?")

So for instance in the `[CDATA...` section, the first "?" is CustomerID (because it's defined as seq=1) and the second "?" is LocationID.

The dataset produced by this is then rendered (as excel / word / pdf etc. by a stylesheet) and presented through the front end for the user to open / save etc.

So.
The first thing I did was to see if I could put the SQL code in a stored procedure, and reference that to return the data:

```
            <![CDATA[ 
                exec dbo.usp_Rep_Customers ?, ?
            ]]>

        </Source>
```

Which worked fine.

Then I tried using a stored procedure for the parameter list:

```
<Prompts>
    <Prompt mandatory="no" datatype="int" name="CustomerID"  label="Customer" dropdownsource="exec usp_Rep_Param_Customers" defaultvalue="0"/>
    <Prompt mandatory="no" datatype="int" name="LocationID"  label="Location" dropdownsource="exec usp_Rep_Param_Locations" defaultvalue="0"/>
</Prompts>
```

Also worked fine.

However, there will be certain circumstances where it would be really useful to limit the values returned in one drop down with the value selected in another: sort of like this:

```
<Prompts>
    <Prompt mandatory="no" datatype="int" name="CustomerID"  label="Customer" dropdownsource="exec usp_Rep_Param_Customers" defaultvalue="0"/>
    <Prompt mandatory="no" datatype="int" name="LocationID"  label="Location" dropdownsource="exec usp_Rep_Param_Locations [pass in parameter of customerID selected in the prompt above which I'll use to limit the list or locations I return]" defaultvalue="0"/>
</Prompts>
```

But because it looks like it renders everything in the `<Prompts>` section at the same time, I don't know if it's even possible to get it to take the selected customerid and pass into the stored procedure to get locations. I had a try using the "?", but because the stuff in `<Prompts>` renders first, setting the Parameter bit to pass in happens in the bit that deals with returning the main report data so hasn't happened.

Also 4 locations is a stupid example, but if the locations drop down was a list of states or counties or something then it would be useful to return a smaller list to select from, or to return a list where you know it's a valid combination do the report will definitely return something.

Understand I'm limited by this being a 3rd party app, but would like to know if anyone's got any xml tricks I could use to do this.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.